# How do you say "that's the point" in Spanish?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, expresiones

If I want to bring up the fact that somebody missed something done on purpose, how would I say that in Spanish?

For example:

> *"The ending was bad. Everybody died!"*
>   *"**That's the point**. It showed the horror of war."*

Comment: Un poco a la antigua: `Ahí donde aprieta el zapato`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to translate "That's the point", some of which have already been mentioned. In the Spanish of most native speakers, "Ese es el punto" is not one of them. It seems, however, that among those who speak a variety of Spanish heavily influenced by English ("Spanglish"), the English calque "Ese es el punto" is heard more and more, and you even find it in writing. To me, it sounds like a barbarism because I am not used to it (40 years living in the US). By the way, this use of the cognate "punto" to translate this particular sense of English "point" extends to other expressions, such as "to make a point", "what's the point?", and so on.

Depending on the context, these expressions can also be equivalent to "That's the point":

Y eso es de lo que se trata. / De eso se trata.

Esa es la cuestión.

Ese es el propósito.

Eso es lo importante.

etc.

Comment: Cognates need not be false. "punto" is defined as follows in DRAE (a Spanish, not Spanglish, dictionary):  30. m. Lo sustancial o principal en un asunto. 31. m. Fin o intento de cualquier acción.

Comment: I'd add "esa es la cosa", "ahí le has dado", and "equilicuá".

Comment: I still think that the word "punto" does not have that sense for most speakers, the DLE notwithstanding, and that it is a very marginal and limited sense. It is certainly not a good way to translate that sense of English "point", since most people won't understand you. No doubt some native speakers do say it and I venture to guess that it is a calque from English in the dialects of those speakers.

Comment: Some (very common) examples of "punto" in the sense of "topic" or "key topic": "Lo consideramos/estudiamos/examinamos punto por punto.", "Otro punto importante es...", "Quería recalcar/subrayar/aclarar este punto.", and so on.

Answer (score 6):

No direct translation sounds good to me. I would suggest:

> Esa es la idea.

Which means:

> That's the idea.

Answer (score 5):

You do have the same sentence in Spanish:

> Ese es el punto. (Also: Ese es el objetivo.)

Alternatively, you can say things like:

> - A eso apunta. (That's what it points to.)

Comment: "Ese es el punto" doesn't sound idiomatic in the context stated by the OP.

Comment: lately i'm seeing a lot more of "ese es el punto" but it really is nothing more than a bad literal translation as of now, which doesn't mean it might become a true translation at some point in time, but as of now, unless the other person knows the english phrase you're most likely to get a puzzled face as a response.

Comment: @BrianH., I see nothing wrong with "ese es el punto" (actually, we very often hear sentences like "ese es precisamente el punto" or "ese es justamente el punto"). However, the other translations proposed are also fine.

Comment: I have never heard such an expression.

Comment: @Jdamian I kindly invite you to check definitions numer 30 and 31 in DRAE, which read as follows: 30. m. Lo sustancial o principal en un asunto. 31. m. Fin o intento de cualquier acción.

Comment: @Gustavson Checking many times those definitions will not make me hear the expression "ese es el punto" more often. My comment above is not about whether that expression is correct or not, but how often I hear it.

Comment: @Jdamian You made it sound like it was an expression out of this world! Here in Argentina I hear it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

As Spuny says, it is not usually convenient to translate word by word. I would suggest using the following expression:

> **De eso se trata.** (Lit.: "That's what it's all about".)

So your example could be translated like this:

> —Qué final más malo, ¡todo el mundo muere!
>   —De eso se trata, de mostrar los horrores de la guerra.

If you want to go more Latin, you can also use ***quid***:

> —Qué final más malo, ¡todo el mundo muere!
>   —Ese es el quid: mostrar los horrores de la guerra.

The word *quid* is [defined by the RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UpHbqdL) as "the essence, the reason of or the most important thing about something".

Answer (score 1):

(Adding to the other answers.) If you want to be ironic, a simple "Exacto!" plus smile works. :-)